# What's the right approach to storing application configuration parameters in an ASP.NET Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration

We have lot of application parameters for each module in a C# .NET 4 ASP website.

parameter examples: timeouts, formulae constants, thread limits per module, $ charges per usage etc.

What is best out of following approaches we know:

1. Use DB config table
2. Use an xml. load that xml into local cache on start (and on xml change)
3. simple constants.cs file with public const int XYZ = 123; type of key-value pairs.
4. web.config (though i think its mostly for deployment type of config)
5. Any other way ?

Help on pros and cons and std. approach followed would be helpful.

Comment: I think you are mixing different kind of setting. `Timeout` is more of an application-wide setting, while `$ charges per usage` depend more on the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like #1, storing the values in the database, for several reasons:

1. This works on a **web farm.** You don't have to synchronize versions of web.config on multiple servers.
2. **Making changes** does not require recompiling and redeploying the application. Changes can be immediate.
3. It is relatively easy to create a **maintenance web page** for authorized users to update the values without bugging production support.
4. The **values can be determined at any time** from outside the application by anybody given access to the database (or to a maintenance page displaying the values). Nobody has to read through the source code or look at web.config files.
5. The web application does not have to be **restarted** for the change to take effect.

**Edit**: Additional comments about the other proposed methods:
If the app is going to be on a **web farm**, all three non-database choices will require **deployment** to all servers. This is not a trivial matter if a lot of web servers are involved, if the deployment procedure is complicated, or if corporate policy severely limits who (and when) changes can be deployed to production servers.

Even when there is no web farm, in a corporate production environment, it can be excruciatingly slow to deploy a change.

Regarding **constants**, I have found that they tend to get sprinkled all over the application code. Finding them can be a real challenge. Of course, if you have the discipline to centralize the configuration constants, you won't have this problem.

There is one other approach not on your list, which is using **resource files (.resx)**. While this is generally used for localization, I have seen it used for configuration values, and especially for storing the text of standard messages. While you don't have to recompile your application to alter a .resx file, changing it will cause the application to restart.

**In summary, then, my reasons for preferring the database approach are the speed and ease of deployment, avoiding recompilations and app restarts, centralizing the data outside the application, and making the data accessible to business users.**

Comment: +1.  As long as reads for the settings aren't expensive for the database, this is a good option.  However, you would have to ask the database for the settings each time you use them since the database can't easily notify your application when they change.  If you're ok with temporarily stale settings, caching can help with this.

Comment: i agree to your points. DB is best for scaling, but rt now our config is already spread out on #2, #3 and #4. :(   Can you comment about those till we get a chance to evaluate DB migration. I personally favour #3 due to its easy addition and access.

Comment: If there is any std. breakup of which kind of values goes where as pointed by Pierre-Alain. then that would be last bit of info to complete this. Like you brought out resx can be used for strings. Timeouts and other app-wide settings in web.config. Otherwise i think i fairly got the pros cons of all methods now and will be able to decide.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to mix different level of setting together:

- `Timeout` is best suited to be part of a web.config file, while
- `$ charges per usage` is more related to a per-user setting and should be located in a database along with the user.

Should you decide to use a web.config file, I suggest the following to keep your web.config file clear of application settings.

Create a file that will store your settings. I usually create a file named as the application, like `nerddinner.config`. Remember that the `config` extension is used for security reason.

Add your setting in the file:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="Test" value="Hello world"/>
</appSettings>
```

In your `web.config` file, create the `<appSetting>`, but redirect it to the other file:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <appSettings configSource="nerddinner.config" />
  ...
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order of preference:

1. Web.config - The main benefit of using web.config is that the application pool is automatically recycled when the file changes.  Also, you have the well-known System.Configuration API for accessing the data.  You shouldn't have to muck around with a separate XML file and monitor it for changes when ASP.NET already has support for configuration files.
2. Constants file - This has the same app pool recycling benefits as the web.config, but it's more likely that you could accidentally introduce new bugs when deploying new assemblies than editing .config files.  If you work in a shop where untrustworthy non-programmers are in charge of the config files, having something compiled in does reduce the chance of entering bad data.
3. Database config table - Fetching configuration data from a database is more complicated than retrieving it from a config file.  Plus, you have to be careful about data locks and other DB goodness.  However, if you need to edit settings at runtime without triggering app pool recycling (unlikely), this is your best bet.
4. XML file - It's easier to use web.config, but this allows you to deploy a file independent of the web.config so it is less-likely to contain potentially-hazardous side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

Well, option 4 (web.config) is safer than option 2 (xml). A .config can't be downloaded so easily.

For the rest it depends a little, there is no 'right' way but i would use a web.config unless there is a really good reason not to. Web.config is not just for 'deployment related' stuff.

Comment: web.config can grow pretty quickly and wont it make difficult to maintain. Also, a change there dynamically disturbs and recompiles full application, whereas custom XML can change independently

Answer (score 1):

1.- Use **DB config table** when you want to change parameters without having to restart your application. Prefer its usage.

2.- Use **xml file**. If your application is XML oriented.

3.- Simple **constants file**. This should not have parameters, constants are not parameters.

4.- **web.config**. Use **appSettings** items for storing simple values that does not change continuously (*DBConnectionTimeout, DBCommandTimeout, PageSize etc..*), use customized **sectionGroup** for more complex parameters.

Here is a simple **configuration table definition**:

```
CREATE TABLE ctr_group_parameters (
    option      varchar(50)  NOT NULL,
    id_group     int          NOT NULL,
    description varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    value       varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (option, id_group) )
```

Answer (score 0):

If these are settings that wouldn't be updated often, I like using web.config. If they are updated a bit more often, I'd think about using a database table.

Comment: ^^ Could you please provide the reason behind your statement?

Comment: web.config is the quickest and easiest to setup and use, AFAIC. So I generally use this for settings like settings for sending email, etc. But if things are changing more often, updating the database can be done without disrupting the application. Having said that, I don't see any hard and fast rules concerning this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the web.config for stuff you know never changes except when it changes along with application logic. For stuff that may need to change independently of code (like $ charges) you may want to use a database.